# Why react native sqlite typescript opendatabase keep return error "TypeError: Cannot convert null value to object"

Tags: typescript, react-native, sqlite, opendatabase

I already put the database file in the path **\android\app\src\main\assets\www** but the openDatabase() always return this error "Error opening database: [TypeError: Cannot convert null value to object]"

Inside the class object

```
class SQLiteWrapper {
    private database: SQLite.SQLiteDatabase | null = null;

... 
  async openDB() {
    if (await RNFS.exists(this.dbFilePath)) {
      SQLite.openDatabase({
        name: this.dbFilePath,
        location: 'default',
      }).then(db => {
        console.info(`Database initialized ... ${db?.dbName}`);
        this.database = db;
        console.info(`Database initialized ... ${this.database?.dbName}`);
      }
      ).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error opening database:', error);
      }
      );
    } else {
      console.error('Error find database:');
    }
  }
```

Usage :

```
      useEffect(() => {
...
        SQLiteWrapper.openDB();
...
      }, []);
```

I am using packages in react-native with typescript "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1" "@types/react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.0"

Already make sure the file can be copy to the location in **this.dbFilePath**

No idea is there the openDatabase looking for different path ? or
typescript problem after opened the database ?

Any suggestions that I missed ?